# When do we use Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>(); and when to use Stack st = new Stack();?

Tags: java, class, object

In Java, when to use

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
```

and when to use

```
Stack st  = new Stack();
```

For `Stack st = new Stack()`, I will have to create my own class `Stack`, other than this is there any other specific differences between them?

Comment: "*For `Stack st = new Stack()` I will have to create my own class Stack*" can you provide more details about your reasoning here?

Comment: Feel free to use [edit] option to correct/clarify that *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 2):

> when to use `Stack st  = new Stack();`?

Never. That style predates the existence of generics in Java. It’s completely replaced by generic usage, i.e. `Stack<Integer>`. Sometimes you need to use late binding and don’t know which type will be stored inside the stack. But even then you’re supposed to use wildcards, i.e. something like `Stack<?>`.

A modern IDE will warn you if you use a generic class without specifying generic parameters.

> I will have to create my own class `Stack`

You don’t, you *could* use the generic `Stack` class (that is, `java.util.Stack<T>`) non-generically. Java allows that (for *any* generic class, not just for `Stack`). But it’s discouraged, see above.